# How to pres select schema in postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

Is there a way I can pre-select a schema in Postgres? My db structure looks like this:

[image]

I want to select the "public" schema first before writing my queries that way I don't have to add .public to every query when making api calls.

I'm using express and here's how I'm connecting:

```html
const client = new Client({
 user: "postgres",
 password: "1234",
 host: 'localhost',
 port: 5432,
 database: 'main'
});
```

Sorry if the question isn't clear. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [search_path setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH), which is a per-connection, user-controlled setting. When resolving a non-schema-qualified table name, each schema in search_path is checked, and the first existing table is used. When creating a table without a schema qualifier, the table is placed in the first existing schema in `search_path`. Note that `public` is in the default search_path already, which is why `create table foo(); select * from foo;` does the Right thing (in both cases, resolving to `public.foo` unless you have some other existing schema earlier in your search_path).